# Peripheral port remapping and alignment on armv6

Tags: assembly, armv6

In the bootloader of an old android tablet, I found a block of code that disables the mmu, then remaps the peripheral port (a transfer to supervisor mode occurs, but isn't shown).

```
ROM:00000064  MOV R0, #0               ; r0 = 0
ROM:00000068  MCR p15, 0, R0,c7,c7, 0  ; invalidate instruction and data cache
ROM:0000006C  MCR p15, 0, R0,c8,c7, 0  ; invalidate tlb
ROM:00000070  MRC p15, 0, R0,c1,c0, 0  ; load the control register
ROM:00000074  BIC R0, R0, #0x2300      ; clear s, r, and v bits (mmu protection disabled, rom protection disabled, select normal exception vector location)
ROM:00000078  BIC R0, R0, #0x87        ; clear m, a, c, and b bits (disable mmu, disable strict alignment fault checking, disable data cache, little endian operation)
ROM:0000007C  ORR R0, R0, #2           ; set bit a (enable strict alignment fault checking)
ROM:00000080  ORR R0, R0, #0x1000      ; set bit I (enable level one instruction cache)
ROM:00000084  MCR p15, 0, R0,c1,c0, 0  ; update control register
ROM:00000088  MOV R0, #0x70000013      ; physical address = 0x70000, region size = 256M
ROM:00000090  MCR p15, 0, R0,c15,c2, 4 ; peripheral port remapped
```

I don't really understand how remapping the peripheral port works.

Page 3-131 of the [ARM1176JZF-S Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0301h/ddi0301h_arm1176jzfs_r0p7_trm.pdf) explains how the register works.

Bits [31:12] set the physical address of the peripheral port (if the mmu is disabled) and bits [4:0] determine the region size.

The selected physical address has to be aligned to region size. I don't really understand what this means.

Given only 20 bits of address space ([31:12]), how do you align to a region size of 256M?

In the case of the above code, what is the actual physical address of the peripheral port after the command has been executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given only 20 bits of address space ([31:12]), how do you align to a region size of 256M?

Although the manual does not state this explicitly, I assume that the 20 bits are the upper 20 bits of a 32-bit address, not the lower ones.

In other words:

The address is not the 20-bit value itself, but the address is the 20-bit value multiplied with 4096.

In this case the region would be aligned to 256M if the 20-bit value is a multiple of 256M/4K = 65536.

> In the case of the above code, what is the actual physical address of the peripheral port after the command has been executed?

If my suspicion is right, the address in the code above would be 0x70000000 and not 0x00070000. However, 0x70000000 is a multiple of 256M.

Comment: Yeah this is a pretty obvious conclusion, especially given where they chose to put that field (at the top of a register)!  So it's more like the register holds a 4k-aligned address, with the low 12 bits being used for other purposes.